# How can you search for an item in a list - python

Tags: python

This is probably a very simple program but I tried to find an item in a list (in python) and it just doesn't seem to work.

I made a simple list called *Names* and had variables:

```
found=False
index=0
```

I made another variable *Searchname* that contains a user entered string (a name) although there seems to be an error.

```
while found==False and index<=(len(Names)-1):
    index=index + 1
    if Searchname==Names[index]:
        found=True

        print('Found')

    else:
        print('Not found')
```

I tried searching for an answer online but they were really complicated and I really hope that there might be some manageable solutions here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is one of the simplest ways to find the index of an item in a list.
I'll use an example to explain this.
Suppose we have a list of fruits(List_Of_Fruits) and we need to find the index of a fruit(Fruit_To_Search),we can use the given code.

The main part is the function index() its syntax is list.index(item) this will give the index of 'item' in 'list'

```js
#A list with a bunch of items(in this case fruits)
List_Of_Fruits = ["Apples" , "Bananas" , "Cherries" , "Melons"]

#Getting an input from the user
Fruit_To_Search = input()

#You can use 'in' to check if something is in a list or string
if Fruit_To_Search in List_Of_Fruits:
  #If the fruit to find is in the list,
  Fruit_Index = List_Of_Fruits.index(Fruit_To_Search)
  #List_Of_Fruits.index(Fruit_to_Search) gives the index of the variable Fruit_to_Search in the list List_Of_Fruits
  print(Fruit_To_Search,"exists in the list. Its index is - ",Fruit_Index)
  
else:
  print(Fruit_To_Search,"does not exist in the list"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [in](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_in.asp) operator simply to check if one element exists or not.

```
item in my_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally to check if an item is in a list you could as Python to check for that.
But this would be case-sensitive. Otherwise you would have to lowercase the list first.

```py
names = ['Mike', 'John', 'Terry']
if 'Mike' in names:
    print ("Found")
else:
    print ("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` operator to search elements in a list. it will return `True` if that element is present in the list else `False`.

```
if Searchname in Names:
    found=True
    print('Found')
else:
    print('Not found')
```