# Python3, If one of the items in the list found "print it" else print "not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print the word found in the list from a website response, else if not found print "Not Found". However my script prints the word it found. But it also prints "Not Found" for every item in the list. I just need it to print "Not Found" if nothing from the list found.

My Script:

```
response = requests.post(URL, headers=Headers, cookies=Cookies, data=Data)

content = response.content
status_type = [b'Approved', b'Pending', b'Rejected', b'Issued']

for status in status_type:
    if status in content:
        print(status.decode())
    if status not in content:
        print("Not Found")
```

Output of My Script:
[image]

Comment: An object will either be in the list or it will not be in the list. So your second statement should use `elif` instead of  `if`

Comment: @Noah, actually an `else` with no condition would do that trick as well but the problem is actually that it prints not found for *each* status not in the content. I think what OP was after was to only print not found if *none* of them were found.

Comment: @paxdiablo , Oh I  see what he meant now.

Comment: Searching an item in a list is a very common algorithm, available in myriad places on line.  Please research the topic before posting a question here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you search for an item in a list - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825971/how-can-you-search-for-an-item-in-a-list-python)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious approach is simply to use a flag to see if any were found:

```
found = False
for status in status_type:
    if status in content:
        print(status.decode())
        found = True
        # break if you only want the first one found
if not found:
    print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag approach of [paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218750/683329) is probably the most straightforward; another approach would be to put to gather the found statuses in a list, then handle it:

```
found_statuses = [status.decode() for status in status_type if status in content]

if found_statuses:
    print(', '.join(found_statuses))
else:
    print('Not Found')
```

This would be particularly useful if you needed to take special action if more than one status is found and need to *not* print them in that case (or print them in a different way):

```
found_statuses = [status.decode() for status in status_type if status in content]

if len(found_statuses) == 1:
    print(found_statuses[0])
elif len(found_statuses) > 1:
    print("Conflicting statuses: %s" % ' and '.join(found_statuses))
else:
    print('Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store your results in another list and print

```
result = [status.decode() for status in status_type if status in content]
if len(result) == 0:
   print("Not Found")
else:
   for status in result:
       print(status)
```